# Use EAV (like) data to get dynamic keys in JSON

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2022

I have a table that contains of EAV like data; this works fine for the application that is using and consuming this data, however, I've been tasked to build some JSON data based on the data in that table.  For the JSON each attribute should be its own key in a JSON object. As, however, there could be additional attributes added at a later date, then I want (need) a solution that will be able to handle those values without a developer needing to add the attribute(s) each time.

Firstly some sample data that's semi-representative of my current table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Vehicle (CustomerID int NOT NULL,
                          VehicleID int NOT NULL,
                          ColumnName varchar(30),
                          ColumnValue varchar(100));

INSERT INTO dbo.Vehicle (CustomerID,
                         VehicleID,
                         ColumnName,
                         ColumnValue)
VALUES(1,1,'Make','Ford'),
      (1,1,'Model','Focus'),
      (1,1,'Colour','Blue'),
      (1,2,'Make','Ford'),
      (1,2,'Model','Fiesta'),
      (1,2,'Colour','Black'),
      (2,1,'Make','Honda'),
      (2,1,'Model','Jazz'),
      (2,1,'Colour','Grey'),
      (2,1,'Transmission','Automatic');
```

And the end goal I'm after for JSON would look like this

```json
[
    {
        "CustomerID": 1,
        "Vehicles": [
            {
                "VehicleID": 1,
                "Make": "Ford",
                "Model": "Focus",
                "Colour": "Blue"
            },
            {
                "VehicleID": 2,
                "Make": "Ford",
                "Model": "Fiesta",
                "Colour": "Black"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "CustomerID": 2,
        "Vehicles": [
            {
                "VehicleID": 1,
                "Make": "Honda",
                "Model": "Jazz",
                "Colour": "Grey",
                "Transmission": "Automatic"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Getting this with static keys isn't a problem, I can use a subquery and some aggregation like so:

```sql
SELECT C.CustomerID,
       (SELECT V.VehicleID,
               MAX(CASE V.ColumnName WHEN 'Make' THEN V.ColumnValue END) AS Make,
               MAX(CASE V.ColumnName WHEN 'Model' THEN V.ColumnValue END) AS Model,
               MAX(CASE V.ColumnName WHEN 'Colour' THEN V.ColumnValue END) AS Colour,
               MAX(CASE V.ColumnName WHEN 'Transmission' THEN V.ColumnValue END) AS Transmission
        FROM dbo.Vehicle V
        WHERE V.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
        GROUP BY V.VehicleID
        FOR JSON PATH) AS Vehicles
FROM dbo.Vehicle C
GROUP BY C.CustomerID
FOR JSON PATH;
```

Getting it to be dynamic, however, I've found to be much harder, and (in fact) the only way I've managed to do it with with `STRING_AGG`, rather than with SQL Server's built in JSON features. My current solution is this:

```sql
WITH Vehicles AS(
    SELECT V.CustomerID,
           V.VehicleID,
           CONCAT('"VehicleID":',V.VehicleID,',',STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"',STRING_ESCAPE(V.ColumnName,'json'),'":"',STRING_ESCAPE(V.ColumnValue,'json'),'"'),',')) AS VehicleDetails
    FROM dbo.Vehicle V
    GROUP BY V.CustomerID,
             V.VehicleID),
Customers AS(
    SELECT V.CustomerID,
           CONCAT('"CustomerID":',V.CustomerID, ',"Vehicles":[{',STRING_AGG(V.VehicleDetails,'},{') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY V.VehicleID ASC),'}]') AS Customer
    FROM Vehicles V
    GROUP BY V.CustomerID)
SELECT CONCAT('[{',STRING_AGG(C.Customer,'},{') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY C.CustomerID), '}]')
FROM Customers C;
```

This, however, feels clunky, harder to maintain, and less likely to be obvious to what it's doing to other members of the development team at the business. Yes, I can take the time explain it, but I feel like there should be a different method to achieve this, but I'm just missing it.

Is there a method to achieve this sort of solution using SQL Server's inbuilt JSON methods? If yes, what is that method? I had a look at `JSON_OBJECT`, `JSON_ARRAY`, however, they didn't seem to help with the "unpivoting".

Comment: What's the actual question? EAV is a very nasty antipattern that makes it impossible to query or even ensure the data is valid. No conversion to XML or JSON will fix that. This isn't about unpivoting, the data is simply stored in a bad format. It's also completely unnecessary - SQL Server can store arbitrary data as XML and can even support up to 32K sparse columns using XML storage

Comment: The actual question is what I've provided, @PanagiotisKanavos ; if I'm unclear, then can you explain what is, and I'll try my best to elaborate.

Comment: @Mogo the problem isn't the size of the title. It's the entire unclear question. `feels clunky, harder to maintain,` yes, that's the problem with EAV and any queries you write will always be as clunky as the antipattern

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I'm not looking to discuss the EAV design; that does work for the application that consumes that. My question is if there is a way to achieve the solution I have, using `STRING_AGG`, with SQL Server's JSON tools (that question was originally in my title); if the answer is simply "No" that is an answer. if the answer is "yes", then I'd like to know what that solution would be.

Comment: The EAV design *is* the problem. The JSON functions expect actual columns, not the names of columns as cell values. You need to unpivot first, which is done either with the UNPIVOT command or multiple self-JOINs. To do so you need to know the column names in advance, or write dynamic SQL that explicitly specifies the column names. SQL queries can't have arbitrary columns

Comment: Ok, so the answer is, effectively, "no", @PanagiotisKanavos . Thank you; that answers my question. I'll stick with the `STRING_AGG` solution and document accordingly.

Comment: i think you're for now stuck to doing things manual way. For what it's worth, I didn't think your code looked that bad. I usually use nested jsons to handle "parent"-children relationships, but not sure it looks better for this kind of code

Comment: Frankly, it would be a lot easier and faster to reshape the data on the client. Pandas for example [has several functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html) that can convert data from long to wide format. A bit too many actually. In C# you could use LINQ to group key-value pairs by ID and convert each group to a Dictionary, dynamic object or JObject

Comment: Interesting @PanagiotisKanavos . I'm not an application developer, unfortunately, so that's "outside my wheel house", but I'll certainly discuss it with our application developers to see if they can perhaps provide a solution on their side.

Comment: @Mogo no, the answer is `do it on the client and fix the broken design`. And check SQL Server's [sparse columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-ver16) and the underlying [XML data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-type-and-columns-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Would XML allow for keys to be added dynamically to the JSON, @PanagiotisKanavos ? My experience with XML's methods in SQL Server is that you need to be specific for each node you want. If you can demonstrate a solution that is dynamic, and uses XML data instead of EAV, that would be really helpful, as I may well be able to use that to push a design change in the future.

Comment: `JSON_OBJECTAGG` aggregate function is coming soon https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/native-json-type-amp-json-aggregates-are-now-in-private-preview/ba-p/3830753, and this would simplify your problem, but for now your only option is indeed `STRING_AGG`. @PanagiotisKanavos The fact is that EAV does occassionally have its place, and this function along with `JSON_ARRAYAGG` are sorely missing from SQL Server at the moment.